# How to get parameters name of method in MethodInterceptor?

Tags: java, aop

I would like to retrieve the parameters's name of a method on MethodInterceptor class.

```
public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
    Method method = invocation.getMethod();
    Class<?> declaringClass = method.getDeclaringClass();
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(declaringClass);
    //here some treatment
    return invocation.proceed();
}
```

and i just can't find how to retrieve with MethodInvocation instance the name of the method parameters. I'm not sure it's possible..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not. Java does not keep the param names in runtime, therefore, the interceptors (or reflection api) do not have way to get that.
One way to solve this is to wrap your params in one class, and have field with names that correspond to your param names.

Answer (score 2):

It **is** possible, as I learned here: [Getting the name of a method parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759880/getting-the-name-of-a-method-parameter/6759953#6759953)

Bellow is an example using the Spring ParameterNameDiscoverer:

```
private Object getParameterName(Method specificMethod, int i) {
    // Project needs to be build with a -g (debug) option to contain information about parameter names.
    ParameterNameDiscoverer discoverer = new LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer();

    String parameterName = discoverer.getParameterNames(specificMethod)[i];
    if (parameterName != null) {
        return parameterName;
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to determine parameter name. Please build the project with -g (debug) option.");
}
```

Comment: This is the way to go, just a few comments: 1. There are several strategies behind ParameterNameDiscoverer to discover parameter names. 2. If you just want parameter name discovery to work without any extra effort (eg adding annotations or such), you need JDK8 3. When using JDK8, use the -parameters flag for javac instead of -g (unless you really need full debug info)