# Getting the name of a method parameter

Tags: java, reflection, runtime, java-6

In **Java 6**, imagine I have the following method signature:

```
public void makeSandwich(Bread slice1, Bread slice2, List<Filling> fillings, boolean mustard)
```

I would like to know, at runtime, the value that was passed on to `slice2` or any other parameter, the important bit here is that I want to get the value by parameter name.

I know how to get the list of parameter types with `getParameterTypes` or `getGenericParameterTypes`.

Ideally I would like to get a list of parameter *names* instead of types. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: This question is about Java 6. For more information about Java 8 onwards, please visit [this tutorial about the `-parameters` option for `javac`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodparameterreflection.html)

Comment: I put mustard at the top AND bottom of my sandwich, `bool` is not specific enough you insensitive clod

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Parameter names are available if you have told the compiler to include them (compile with debug information). Spring has  [`ParameterNameDiscoverer`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/core/ParameterNameDiscoverer.html) which can help you obtain the names. The [default implementation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/core/LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.html) uses asm [`ClassReader`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm33/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassReader.html) to do so.

With `javac` you should include the `-g` argument to include debug information. With Eclipse I think it is there by default; it can be configured using the preferences: Java -> Compiler and then enable "Store information about method parameters (usable via reflection)" (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37021110/589259)).

Some frameworks use this. For example spring-mvc has `@RequestParam` which defaults to the param name, if resolvable. It also supports explicit naming - `@RequestParam("foo")` in case no debug information is provided.

Comment: Thanks, I am not using spring. Do you know where I can find some usage examples for `ClassReader`?

Comment: look at the inspectClass(..) method here https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-framework/trunk/org.springframework.core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java

Comment: Link is broken. `inspectClass()` seems to have been removed from [Spring 3.0.x](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/core/LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.html).

Comment: Does any one know how can I add the debug information when I'm using Maven?

Comment: Link broken to Spring source, see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/tree/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core. Helped hint the issue I had for my code (related to long/double variables).

Comment: How can do this in IntelliJ or Gradle?

Answer (score 11):

I have found another solution after marking this question as answered. The solution is [Paranamer](https://github.com/paul-hammant/paranamer).

Example:

```
 Method method = Foo.class.getMethod(...);

 Paranamer paranamer = new CachingParanamer();

 String[] parameterNames = paranamer.lookupParameterNames(method) // throws ParameterNamesNotFoundException if not found

 // or ...

 parameterNames = paranamer.lookupParameterNames(method, false) // will return null if not found
```

Answer (score 7):

Since Java 1.8, this can be done **as long as the parameter names are in the class files**. Using `javac` this is done passing the `-parameters` flag. From the `javac` help

```
-parameters    Generate metadata for reflection on method parameters
```

From IDEs you will need to look at the compiler settings.

If the parameter names are in the class files then here is an example of doing this

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Parameter;

public class ParameterNamesExamples {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Method theDoSomethingMethod = ExampleClass.class.getMethods()[0];
    // Now loop through the parameters printing the names
    for(Parameter parameter : theDoSomethingMethod.getParameters()) {
      System.out.println(parameter.getName());
    }
  }

  private class ExampleClass {
    public void doSomething(String myFirstParameter, String mySecondParameter) {
      // No-op
    }
  }
}
```

The output will depend on **if the parameter names are in the class files**. If they are the output is:

```
myFirstParameter
mySecondParameter
```

If not the output is:

```
arg0
arg1
```

More information on this from Oracle can be found at [Obtaining Names of Method Parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodparameterreflection.html)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6759953/3576344) answer:
"Parameter names are available if you have told the compiler to include them"

If you're using Eclipse go to project -> properties -> Java Compiler -> check "Store information about method parameters (usable via reflection)

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. Class files do not contains the argument names, as you can see with your IDE's autocompletion when the source is not available.

Therefore, the reflection API is not able to give out parameter names.

Comment: Any other way, even without reflection?

Comment: I suggest using a `HashMap` containing variants. Or, (but it seems crafty to me), looking at how the IDE does extract the parameter names from the source JAR.

Comment: You would have to log it yourself.

Comment: not entirely true. parameter names can be included (I think the eclipse compiler does that by default, for example)

Comment: "Class files do not contain the argument names". You may be able to do some trickery if you also have the source files. As @kbok mentions, IDEs show argument names on methods if the source is available.

Comment: From Java 1.8 onwards this is possible see other answers

Answer (score 2):

In Java parameter names are not available via reflection.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply assign the value of the parameter to another value

```
Bread slice2;

public void makeSandwich(Bread slice1, Bread slice2, List<Filling> fillings, boolean mustard) {
    this.slice2 = slice2;
    System.out.println(this.slice2.getSomething());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you own the code of the method? You could annotate the parameters and pass names as arguments `@Param("slice1")`. Later you will be able to get the annotation and extract parameter name from it.