# How to get parameter names with Java reflection

Tags: java, reflection, method-signature

How do I get method signatures with Java reflection?

EDIT:
**I actually need the parameter NAMES not the types of a method.**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get the method i of a class C you call `C.class.getMethods()[i].toString()`.

**EDIT:** Obtaining **parameter names** is *not* possible using the reflection API.

But wen you compiled your class with debug information, it is possible to extract the information from bytecode. Spring does it using the [ASM bytecode engineering library](http://asm.ow2.org).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6759953/691083) for further information.

Answer (score 3):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#toString()

use the `toString()` method of `java.lang.reflect.Method` object for the method you are looking for.

If you want to know how to get that method object just use this as a reference:

```
Method toString = Class.forName("java.lang.String").getDeclaredMethod("toString");
System.out.println(toString);
```

and it prints:

> public java.lang.String java.lang.String.toString()

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class method1 {
    private int f1(Object p, int x) throws NullPointerException
    {
        if (p == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        return x;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try {
            Class cls = Class.forName("method1");

            Method methlist[] = cls.getDeclaredMethods();
            for (int i = 0; i < methlist.length; i++) {
                Method m = methlist[i];
                System.out.println("name = " + m.getName());
                System.out.println("decl class = " + m.getDeclaringClass());
                Class pvec[] = m.getParameterTypes();
                for (int j = 0; j < pvec.length; j++)
                    System.out.println("param #" + j + " " + pvec[j]);
                Class evec[] = m.getExceptionTypes();
                for (int j = 0; j < evec.length; j++)
                    System.out.println("exc #" + j + " " + evec[j]);
                System.out.println("return type = " + m.getReturnType());
                System.out.println("-----");
            }
        }
        catch (Throwable e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/