# How can i get the `signature` field of java reflection Method object

Tags: java, reflection

i'm using ASM to build class file base on another `Interface` , i could use java reflection to get methods of the `Interface` , but i need to get the signature of it . 
[image]

i found it's a private field , and there's no direct method to get it . is there any way out ? i use jdk7 . 
tks advance .

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodType.html ?

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081212/how-to-get-parameter-names-with-java-reflection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you want is the `signature` field of `java.lang.reflect.Method`, that's simple:

```
java.lang.reflect.Field f = java.lang.reflect.Method.class.getDeclaredField("signature");
f.setAccessible(true);
String sigature = f.get(yourMethod);
```

Where `yourMethod` is a Method object.

Keep in mind: The signature field simply denotes the signature of a generic method, so attempting to get the signature of a non-generic method will simply return `null`.

For example, let's assess the following method:

```
public static <T> void test(Class<T> c){}
```

This will return a signature of `<T:Ljava/lang/Object;>(Ljava/lang/Class<TT;>;)V`

This shows that the method declares one generic type 
that must at least inherit `java.lang.Object` and takes a class of that type as a parameter.

But, say we were to remove the generic from the method:

```
public static void test(Class c){}
```

This would result in the `signature` field being `null`.

**Edit:**

If you want to get the signature of any method (generic or not), there are a couple of ways to do it, but I find the following to be the most concise (although possibly clunky):

```
public static String getSignature(Method m){
    String sig;
    try {
        Field gSig = Method.class.getDeclaredField("signature");
        gSig.setAccessible(true);
        sig = (String) gSig.get(m);
        if(sig!=null) return sig;
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("(");
    for(Class<?> c : m.getParameterTypes()) 
        sb.append((sig=Array.newInstance(c, 0).toString())
            .substring(1, sig.indexOf('@')));
    return sb.append(')')
        .append(
            m.getReturnType()==void.class?"V":
            (sig=Array.newInstance(m.getReturnType(), 0).toString()).substring(1, sig.indexOf('@'))
        )
        .toString();
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the way i wannted , before your method , i concatenate the strings myself . that's painful and ugly codes . tks a lot!

Comment: @Adams.H since you said you’re using the ASM library, you could have used the [`Type`](https://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/org/objectweb/asm/Type.html) class which does all sorts of conversion in the first place. With built-in Java facilities, you could have used [`MethodType.methodType().toMethodDescriptorString(m.getReturnType(), m.getParameterTypes())`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/MethodType.html#toMethodDescriptorString()) since Java 7. Accessing the `signature` field does not work with recent Java versions.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing '.' with '/' makes Gabriel Tofvesson's answer complete:

```
... .toString().replace('.', '/');
```

Otherwise, the signature returned would be something like `()Ljava.lang.Object;`. However, in signatures, the package names must be separated using slashes instead of periods: `()Ljava/lang/Object;`.

Comment: @MichalŠtein I just tried this out: Gabriel Tofvesson's code returned `"(ILjava.lang.String;)I"` in my example; `"(ILjava/lang/String;)I"` would be correct.

Comment: @DexterHaxxor what is “it” and what does it not do?

Comment: I have no idea what I was thinking 4 years ago.

Answer (score -1):

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html) is a map from letter to type signataure.

> **Type Signature  ->  Java Type**
> Z  ->  boolean
> B  ->  byte
> C  ->  char
> S  ->  short
> I  ->  int
> J  ->  long
> F  ->  float
> D  ->  double
> Lfully-qualified-class;  ->  fully-qualified-class
> [ type                   ->  type[]
> (arg-types)ret-type      ->  method type

```
// Holds a mapping from Java type names to native type codes.
private static final Map<Class<?>, String> PRIMITIVE_TO_SIGNATURE;
static {
    PRIMITIVE_TO_SIGNATURE = new HashMap<Class<?>, String>(9);
    PRIMITIVE_TO_SIGNATURE.put(byte.class, "B");
    PRIMITIVE_TO_SIGNATURE.put(char.class, "C");
    PRIMITIVE_TO_SIGNATURE.put(short.class, "S");
    PRIMITIVE_TO_SIGNATURE.put(int.class, "I");
    PRIMITIVE_TO_SIGNATURE.put(long.class, "J");
    PRIMITIVE_TO_SIGNATURE.put(float.class, "F");
    PRIMITIVE_TO_SIGNATURE.put(double.class, "D");
    PRIMITIVE_TO_SIGNATURE.put(void.class, "V");
    PRIMITIVE_TO_SIGNATURE.put(boolean.class, "Z");
}

/**
 * Returns the internal name of {@code clazz} (also known as the descriptor).
 */
public static String getSignature(Class<?> clazz) {
    String primitiveSignature = PRIMITIVE_TO_SIGNATURE.get(clazz);
    if (primitiveSignature != null) {
        return primitiveSignature;
    } else if (clazz.isArray()) {
        return "[" + getSignature(clazz.getComponentType());
    } else {
        return "L" + clazz.getName().replace('.', '/') + ";";
    }
}
```

then, we get signature from java.lang.reflect.Method like this:

```
public static String getSignature(Method method) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    result.append('(');
    Class<?>[] parameterTypes = method.getParameterTypes();
    for (Class<?> parameterType : parameterTypes) {
        result.append(getSignature(parameterType));
    }
    result.append(')');
    result.append(getSignature(method.getReturnType()));
    return result.toString();
}
```

we print java.lang.Object class all methods' signature:

```
Method[] methods = Object.class.getDeclaredMethods();
for(Method method: methods) {
    String signature = getSignature(method);
    System.out.println(method.getName() + "  " + signature);
}
```

and it prints

> finalize  ()V
> wait  (J)V
> wait  (JI)V
> wait  ()V
> equals  (Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
> toString  ()Ljava/lang/String;
> hashCode  ()I
> getClass  ()Ljava/lang/Class;
> clone   ()Ljava/lang/Object;
> notify  ()V
> notifyAll  ()V
> registerNativces  ()V

Above are some Java codes. we can also get signature from Java builtin command **javap**, -s for signature info. For example, we can get java.lang.Object class with this command `javap -s java.lang.Object`:

> Compiled from "Object.java"
> public class java.lang.Object {
> public java.lang.Object();
> descriptor: ()V
>
> public final native java.lang.Class<?> getClass();
> descriptor: ()Ljava/lang/Class;
>
> public native int hashCode();
> descriptor: ()I
>
> public boolean equals(java.lang.Object);
> descriptor: (Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
>
> protected native java.lang.Object clone() throws java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException;
> descriptor: ()Ljava/lang/Object;
>
> public java.lang.String toString();
> descriptor: ()Ljava/lang/String;
>
> public final native void notify();
> descriptor: ()V
>
> public final native void notifyAll();
> descriptor: ()V
>
> public final void wait() throws java.lang.InterruptedException;
> descriptor: ()V
>
> public final native void wait(long) throws java.lang.InterruptedException;
> descriptor: (J)V
>
> public final void wait(long, int) throws java.lang.InterruptedException;
> descriptor: (JI)V
>
> protected void finalize() throws java.lang.Throwable;
> descriptor: ()V
>
> static {};
> descriptor: ()V
> }

Comment: Did you read the question? It is about the **generic** signature. Your code doesn't produce that.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn what do you mean by saying generic?

Comment: See [JVMS §4.7.9.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.9.1)

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I did read the question and I didn’t encounter the word generic at all. The accepted answer points out that this field holds generic signatures only, but that’s not sufficient to retroactively reinterpret the question.