# Field exists but NoSuchFieldException

Tags: java, reflection

I have simple code where I try to get the signature of a field:

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Main {

    static class Test {
        int hi =  1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException {
        Field hi = Test.class.getDeclaredField("hi");

        // getting "signature" field from Field
        Field field = Field.class.getDeclaredField("signature");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        String signature = (String) field.get(hi);

        System.out.println(signature);
    }
}
```

however, I am getting this exception:

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: signature
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:2663)
    at Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

Comment: Can you clarify why you believe that `java.lang.reflect.Field` should have a field named `signature`? Did you get that from an article somewhere, or something?

Comment: `Field field = Field.class.getDeclaredField("signature");` does not refer to anything in your code.  This is asking `Class<Field>` to return a reference to some internal member called `signature`.  I don't think that's what you intended.

Comment: @ruakh the `Field` class has a field called `signature` declared like this:
`private final transient String    signature;`

Comment: @JimGarrison yes this is what I intended.

Comment: See https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8210522 for an explanation.

Comment: As always, it needs to be mentioned that private fields of Java SE are private for a reason.  Programmers are not entitled to have access to them, and Java is under no obligation to keep them in future versions.  If a private field in a Java SE class changes or gets removed, it’s not a defect in Java, it’s a defect in your code, for making assumptions that were never safe to make.

Comment: The `signature` field will be predictably `null` in your case. Why do you think you needed access to that field?

Comment: @Holger I'm doing JNI stuff and too lazy to manually get signature

Comment: Ahh, a classic [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). First of all, this field holds the signature for *generic types*. That’s why this field will be `null` in the example above. Which demonstrates why it is a bad idea to use internals whose purpose you don’t understand, especially not to serve your laziness. Solving your actual problem is not that hard, `field.getType().descriptorString()` will give you what you want, at least in Java 12 and newer. If it does not work for you, ask a question about your problem, not attempted solution.

Comment: @Holger Thanks. I didn't know about `descriptorString()` before. I didn't post my original problem because there was another answer on stack overflow about something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45072268/how-can-i-get-the-signature-field-of-java-reflection-method-object).

Answer (score 2):

JDK9 introduced [modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System) and with every release OpenJDK has been breaking backwards compatibility and removing abilities to introspect other modules. That's what you're running into. If you want to do this, downgrade to at least JDK11, possibly JDK8, and know that you can't upgrade. Alternatively, you can try `--add-opens` to open up the relevant modules but whomever runs your code will have to know what bevy of `--add-opens` switches you need to pass to the java executable. And I'm not even sure if that actually lets you introspect into private members of `java.lang` stuff.

It *sounds* like you are attempting to read the generics out of a field. You can do that without resorting to reflecting on `private` stuff in the `java.base` module which requires hacks on modern JVMs.

You use [`field.getGenericType()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getGenericType()) for that.

There is nothing in `field.signature` that I'm aware of that you can't also get with `getGenericType()`, so, just use that. I don't think it's worthwhile extending this answer to explain how to use `--add-opens` here, as it's clearly the inferior solution.

Comment: What is here at play has nothing to do with modules, and is reflection filtering, which did already exist in Java 8 and earlier. (Try to find the `security` field of the `System` class in Java 8 - you won't find it).

Comment: For more information: https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8210522