# How to get name of method parameter/argument in groovy?

Tags: reflection, groovy

I have groovy script that has a function with 2 arguments, one of which is a hashmap. I want to check the name of a hashmap variable contains a substring or not, inside a function. How do i do it?

```
def myfunc(String var, HashMap var2)
{
    // need a routine to retrive the name of the variable var2
}
```

Comment: "need a routine to retrive the name of the variable var2" doesn't make sense.  var2 is the name of the variable.  Can you clarify whatever it is you think you want to be able to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's well explained here : 
[Getting the name of a method parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759880/getting-the-name-of-a-method-parameter/6759953#6759953)

To access groovy script's method follow syntax :

`metaClass.methods`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want the [`--parameters`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#section-groovy-commandline) (alias `-pa`) compiler argument.

> Generates metadata for reflection on method parameter names on JDK 8 and above. Defaults to false.

Usage: `groovy --parameters Person.groovy`

Also available for `groovyc`, `groovyConsole`, `groovysh` and groovy `ant tasks`. Check out the PR [some awesome person](https://github.com/apache/groovy/pull/38/files) contributed...

e.g.

```
class HelloWorld {
   static void speak(String firstName) {
      println "Hello $firstName"   
   } 
}

Student.methods.each { 
    if (it.name === 'speak') println it.parameters
}

// groovy HelloWorld.groovy => "[java.lang.String arg0]"
// groovy -pa HelloWorld.groovy => "[java.lang.String firstName]"
```