# Is it possible to get the name of variable in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming, katalon-studio

I would like to know if it is possible to retrieve the name of a variable.

For example if I have a method:

```
def printSomething(def something){
//instead of having the literal String something, I want to be able to use the name of the variable that was passed
println('something is: ' + something)
}
```

If I call this method as follows:

```
 def ordinary = 58
 printSomething(ordinary)
```

I want to get:

```
ordinary is 58
```

On the other hand if I call this method like this:

```
def extraOrdinary = 67
printSomething(extraOrdinary)
```

I want to get:

```
extraOrdinary is 67
```

**Edit**

I need the variable name because I have this snippet of code which runs before each **TestSuite** in *Katalon Studio*, basically it gives you the flexibility of passing GlobalVariables using a katalon.features file. The idea is from: [kazurayam/KatalonPropertiesDemo](https://github.com/kazurayam/KatalonPropertiesDemo)

```
  @BeforeTestSuite
    def sampleBeforeTestSuite(TestSuiteContext testSuiteContext) {
        KatalonProperties props = new KatalonProperties()
        // get appropriate value for GlobalVariable.hostname loaded from katalon.properties files
        WebUI.comment(">>> GlobalVariable.G_Url default value: \'${GlobalVariable.G_Url}\'");

//gets the internal value of GlobalVariable.G_Url, if it's empty then use the one from katalon.features file
            String preferedHostname = props.getProperty('GlobalVariable.G_Url')
            if (preferedHostname != null) {
                GlobalVariable.G_Url = preferedHostname;
                WebUI.comment(">>> GlobalVariable.G_Url new value: \'${preferedHostname}\'");
            } else {
                WebUI.comment(">>> GlobalVariable.G_Url stays unchanged");
            }
 //doing the same for other variables is a lot of duplicate code
        }
```

Now this only handles 1 variable value, if I do this for say 20 variables, that is a lot of duplicate code, so I wanted to create a helper function:

```
def setProperty(KatalonProperties props, GlobalVariable var){
   WebUI.comment(">>> " + var.getName()" + default value: \'${var}\'");

//gets the internal value of var, if it's null then use the one from katalon.features file
            GlobalVariable preferedVar = props.getProperty(var.getName())
            if (preferedVar != null) {
                var = preferedVar;
                WebUI.comment(">>> " + var.getName() + " new value: \'${preferedVar}\'");
            } else {
                WebUI.comment(">>> " + var.getName() + " stays unchanged");
            }
}
```

Here I just put var.getName() to explain what I am looking for, that is just a method I assume.

Comment: @Carcigenicate it's not purely out of curiosity, I need to use the variable name for passing it to a function: `KatalonProperties.getProperty(String key)` which retrieves the value of a property based on the name of the property. I can change the parameter to be a String instead of **def** to control what is passed to my function...but I still need to know how to get the name of a variable

Comment: No, it's not possible

Comment: @tim_yates well that's a bummer :(

Comment: The stack would be immense 

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319732/how-to-get-name-of-a-variable-in-groovy

Comment: @AdityaT don't think it's a duplicate. That's about getting the argument name. This is about getting the name of the variable that was passed to the method

Comment: @tim_yates Looks legit, my bad. :)

Comment: @tim_yate isn't that possible with Macro-Methods, or am I wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with ASTTransformations or with Macros (Groovy 2.5+).

I currently don't have a proper dev environment, but here are some pointers:

Not that both options are not trivial, are not what I would recommend a Groovy novice and you'll have to do some research. If I remember correctly either option requires a separate build/project from your calling code to work reliable. Also either of them might give you obscure and hard to debug compile time errors, for example when your code expects a variable as parameter but a literal or a method call is passed. So: there be dragons. That being said: I have worked a lot with these things and they can be really fun ;)

[Groovy Documentation for Macros](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/#_macros)

If you are on Groovy 2.5+ you can use Macros. For your use-case take a look at the `@Macro methods` section. Your Method will have two parameters: `MacroContext macroContext, MethodCallExpression callExpression` the latter being the interesting one. The [MethodCallExpression](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/ast/expr/MethodCallExpression.html) has the `getArguments()`-Methods, which allows you to access the Abstract Syntax Tree Nodes that where passed to the method as parameter. In your case that should be a [VariableExpression](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/ast/expr/VariableExpression.html) which has the `getName()` method to give you the name that you're looking for.

[Developing AST transformations](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/#developing-ast-xforms)

This is the more complicated version. You'll still get to the same `VariableExpression` as with the Macro-Method, but it'll be tedious to get there as you'll have to identify the correct `MethodCallExpression` yourself. You start from a `ClassNode` and work your way to the `VariableExpression` yourself. I would recommend to use a local transformation and create an Annotation. But identifying the correct `MethodCallExpression` is not trivial.

Comment: that sounds like too much work for my level of expertise :(

Comment: Didn't mean to discourage you :/ But maybe best to learn the basics and then come back. Groovy is super powerful and becomes even more powerful when you start to play with the AST ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since [Groovy 4.0](https://groovy-lang.org/releasenotes/groovy-4.0.html), it is possible to do that using `NV` and `SV` macro.

```
def printSomethingNV(def something) {
    println("NV $something.name is : $something.val")
}

def printSomethingSV(def something) {
    def (name, val) = something.split('=')
    println("SV $name is : $val")
}

def ordinary = 58
printSomethingNV(NV(ordinary))
printSomethingSV(SV(ordinary))

def extraOrdinary = 67
printSomethingNV(NV(extraOrdinary))
printSomethingSV(SV(extraOrdinary))

// Output
// NV ordinary is : 58
// SV ordinary is : 58
// NV extraOrdinary is : 67
// SV extraOrdinary is : 67
```

Answer (score -1):

no. it's not possible.

however think about using map as a parameter and passing name and value of the property:

```
def printSomething(Map m){
    println m
}

printSomething(ordinary:58)
printSomething(extraOrdinary:67)
printSomething(ordinary:11,extraOrdinary:22)
```

this will output

```
[ordinary:58]
[extraOrdinary:67]
[ordinary:11, extraOrdinary:22]
```

Comment: Wrong answer. It is possible to get the name of variable.

Comment: Apologies dude, I actually mistook the question, right I am not sure if its possible or not. :D 
Can you edit the answer to clarify the point that its possible for method arguments but not for variable name. :)

Comment: @AdityaT if it's possible for method arguments, then I can work with that too.

Comment: Ok , I will add a answer than.

Comment: @AdityaT looking forward to your answer.

Comment: Well, I have to admit it's not possible or I don't know how to get it done, the link I posted for being duplicate is actually not working I tried that myself before actually posting an answer, but metaClass didn't seem to contain any information on variable or method parameters.

Comment: I  am not sure why was metaClass.methods accepted as answer in that post.