# Java method name analyzer

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am indexing the request logs from a java app and the logs contain key method names and time taken. The method names are full method names like

```
com.example.domain.File[] com.example.service.FolderService.getFiles() throws com.example.Exception
```

In order to search for a method name or type (like getfiles or File) I believe I need to define a custom analyzer so that it tokenizes the package and method names. Does such an analyzer already exist?

I verified that I can map the field as not_analyzed and use a wildcard for the search. But the docs say that using a wildcard is not very performant and recommends preparing the index correctly.

Looking for other suggestions, ideas as well.

Comment: Did you take a look at [Soot](http://sable.github.io/soot/)? It is a static analyser which can give you what you need and much much more!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't have all the requirements set, yet. Here's what I'd start with:

```
PUT /index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "code": {
          "type": "pattern_capture",
          "preserve_original": 1,
          "patterns": [
            "(\\p{Ll}+|\\p{Lu}\\p{Ll}+|\\p{Lu}+)",
            "(\\d+)"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "code": {
          "tokenizer": "pattern",
          "filter": [
            "code",
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "code": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "code"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Test data:

```
POST /index/test/1
{
  "code": "com.example.domain.File[] com.example.service.FolderService.getFiles() throws com.example.Exception"
}
```

Query:

```
GET /index/test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "code": "File"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, sounds like the pattern analyzer is what I need (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-analyzer.html)

Answer (score 0):

Is the code a part of your project, or something you are just reading in as input?

If it is in your project, you can accomplish this with [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/). The Spring framework is able to do it, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759880/getting-the-name-of-a-method-parameter/6759953#6759953).