# How can get argument values from @DataProvider for @Test in @Before and @AfterMethod anotation in TestNG

Tags: automated-tests, testng, dataprovider, testng-dataprovider

I would like to get argument names and their values from @Test in TestNG. These arguments are provided by @DataProvider. Normally, I can store it in variables of class by its not good idea when i would like to run test parallel. Here is my code:

```
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestHomePage{

    @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setup(Method method) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("INFO ====setup===:" + method.getName());
        // how can I get parameters and value from @Test?
        //ex: sLogin="notLogin";sLike=""
    }

    @AfterMethod()
    public void tearnDown(Method method) {
        System.out.println("INFO ====tearnDown===:" + method.getName());
        // how can I get parameters and value from @Test?
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "likedata", parallel = true)
    public Object[][] likeDataprovider() throws Exception {
        return new Object[][] { { "notLogin", "" }, { "loggedIn", "notLike" }, { "loggedIn", "liked" } };
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "likedata")
    public void verifyLikeFunction(String sLogin, String sLike, Method method) throws Exception {
        // Test
    }

}
```

Any one can help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value, Add `params`as parameter of `@BeforeMethod`

```
 @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setup(Method method, Object[] params) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("INFO ====setup===:" + method.getName());
        
        System.out.println("Parameter value:");
        for (Object parameter : params) {
            System.out.println(parameter);
        }      
    }
```

Take look at [Dependency Injection in TestNG](https://simpleseleniumwithjava.blogspot.com/2014/12/dependency-injection-in-testng.html) for more info.

And to get parameter name,

```
  @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setup(Method method, Object[] params) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Before , INFO ====setup===:" + method.getName());
       
        Parameter[] parameters= method.getParameters();
        
        System.out.println("Parameter names:");
        for (Parameter parameter : parameters) {
            System.out.println(parameter.getName());
        }     
    }
```

Getting parameter names are possible if debug information is included during compilation. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759880/getting-the-name-of-a-method-parameter/6759953#6759953) for more details

Simply,
If you're using Eclipse go to project -> properties -> Java Compiler -> check "Store information about method parameters (usable via reflection)

Same we can do in `@AfterMethod`.

Comment: I tried do the same ways as you said but before reading your answers. Anyways, thanks